# Sample Android Launcher is in phone resolution and I need to edit it for a tablet screen

Tags: android, eclipse, launcher, blurry

I'm editing the sample Android home launcher in 2.3.3 and it's in a resolution for phones. There's a million instances of

```
android:layout_width="78dip"
android:layout_height="65dip"
```

And they're mostly all different. I want it to expand and be NOT blurry on all resolutions. So basically I want it to be not specific and auto fit.

Answer (score 1):

I am not so sure about this myself, but apparently now everything is no longer blurry in my phone (SIII no root Android 4.1.2). I tried to suppress all warnings (using Eclipse), and it just became sharp, though the icons becomes very small.

I believe this is because I specify the API version. The icons are small because there is some part in the code which makes the app PPI not maximised for my phone.

So on the AndroidManifest.xml, some changes I made (really not sure which part makes it good):

- I added versionName and versionCode to manifest
- I added uses-sdk to min API level 14 (that's Android 4.0) and target and max 18 (Android 4.3) - I suspect this enables high resolution (if I am not mistaken, following Android version changes)
- due to uses-sdk, I needed to suppress warning on allowBackup

There is something wrong with stackoverflow coding block, so I will use Snipt for my AndroidManifest. Here is the link: https://snipt.net/hansccwolf/sharp-resolution-of-android-home-sample-androidmanifestxml/

**Update:**
I managed to make the icons in the recent/favorite big<del>, though not yet for the all apps</del>.

- In ApplicationsStackLayout.java's constructor with two parameters, replace the value of
  `mIconSize` from `42` to the comment (`(int)getResources().getDimension(android.R.dimen.app_icon_size`);
- In Home.java, search for similar comments. Uncomment the width and height. Also uncomment the line before width and height on resources. Eclipse gave warning to me then to import Resources.

While the icon sizes are now correct, in my phone, their margins are inexistent which causes the icons to be cramped and some of their titles overlapped by the icons.

Comment: You are great !

Answer (score 0):

I think you must use "android:layout_height="65dp" "dp", but I am not sure if is this the same think.